# Need explanation for failed Triage review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, triage

I just failed [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7639005)

I do not fully understand why. In my eyes, the question would be salvageable if the author improved it, hence I clicked "Should be improved". Since the question was already deleted, I failed this audit.

While I totally understand the fact that one might have the opinion that the original question was unsalvageable, I do not understand why the idea that the question could be improved leads to a failed audit. It is not that this question was considered ok.

Comment: "the question would be salvageable if the author improved it" - meaning it's completely useless to send it to the "Help and Improvement" queue, which is what "Should be improved" does. The question should be closed as "unclear" if it needs more info that only the author can provide. Please inform yourself what the buttons in the review queue actually do before you click them.

Comment: @l4mpi: The explanation states "**Should Be Improved** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable". So, as far as I understand you, it is to be judged if it is likely that a) either the author or others *will* find the question worth editing and b) that somebody is willing to put the necessary work into the question?

Comment: Yes, the explanation sucks - that's repeatedly mentioned on meta. If a triage item is reviewed as "Should be improved", it is sent to the "Help and Improvement" queue. The purpose of that queue is for users to edit this question into shape. If a question, as you say, can only be salvaged by the author, sending it to the H&I queue is a waste of everybodys time. There is however a _close reason_ (two, actually) for that exact case; thus the question should be closed, which can be done by clicking the unfortunately-named "unsalvageable" button (which really means "unsalvageable by _others_").

Comment: @l4mpi: Thank you for your time! Will enjoy my 2 day break from reviewing, now ;) Answering questions, instead.

Comment: @l4mpi yeah... that stuff really should be explained more clearly.