# What's the point of audits in the Triage Review Queue?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, triage

(I've tested this, and it works)

If someone chooses 'Requires Editing' for every post in their Review Queue, they will never fail an audit. So what's the point of having one when it can be fooled so easily?

Comment: If you're downvoting, please can you explain why?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you've just admitted to jamming the review queue with bogus reviews to test out this theory of yours.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield You're right, but I thought I made it clear that I did this to prove that there's a problem with the auditing process for the triage review queue

Comment: The audit process is not a policing function. Just because it's possible for you to lie to it doesn't make it faulty.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield But it renders the process ineffective

Comment: Ineffective at what?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Ineffective at checking whether the reviewer is paying attention

Comment: Yes, but the audit process is only interested in making sure that actual reviewers (not robo-reviewers) are paying attention. There are other mechanisms to deal with robo-reviewing, I'm sure.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield So the audit process is only used to check whether a human is reviewing the queue??

Comment: No, robo-reviewers are those users who plow through the review queue reviewing as many posts as possible (with no thought to accuracy) to earn badges and what-not.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Butrobo-reviewers could just click 'Requires Editing' all the time and then they wouldn't fail any audits.

Comment: Exactly -- because the audit process is not intended to stop robo-reviewers, per se. It does do a good job (IMO) of "nudging the elbow" of a _casual_ robo-reviewer (one that slips into inattentiveness after a lengthy list of reviews). Think of it as a low guardrail, not a high brick wall.

Comment: Are you saying that if you use Requires Editing on a post the audit system considers good, it will tell you that you passed the audit? And that it'll do the same thing with a question the system considers Unsalvageable? If so, this is a bug.

Comment: Can you link to the audits that show that this is happening?

Comment: If someone never review anything, he will never fail an audit.

Answer (score 13):

Requires Editing is treated the same as Looks OK in Triage audits; either way you're saying the question should stay on the site. Related Meta questions:

- [Weird audit "requires editing"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349382/weird-audit-requires-editing)
- [What does a triage review audit with correct answer "Requires Editing" mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316549/what-does-a-triage-review-audit-with-correct-answer-requires-editing-mean)

However, choosing Requires Editing on an unsalvageable question should cause you to fail the audit:

- [Need explanation for failed Triage review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289874/need-explanation-for-failed-triage-review-audit)
- ["Requires editing" wrong for a foreign language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318193/requires-editing-wrong-for-a-foreign-language)
- [Reviewing triage queue, failed audit for unknown (to me) reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344505/reviewing-triage-queue-failed-audit-for-unknown-to-me-reason)

Since the only [audit in your recent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18929481) was for a post that has a score of 11 (and could legitimately use editing for that matter) it doesn't look like you've found a bug or a flaw in the system.

Also, don't do bogus reviews just to test something. If you think you encountered something strange or a bug, just come to meta. Employees have ways to test stuff without messing up real reviews.